How to use conditional panel in R Shiny to only hide and show user inputs while still allowing underlying calculations to run?
In the below R Shiny code, I am using a conditionalPanel() to show/hide optional user inputs into "child X/Y tables" for including additional variables into mathematical operations. I only want the conditionalPanel() to hide (and show) additional user inputs, into the child X/Y tables that render in the sidebarPanel(), while allowing the calculations to run as if these user inputs were not hidden and thus render in the mainPanel() the output table called mainTbl regardless of whether or not the checkboxInput() is checked. How can this be done?
These images explain. This first image is what appears when the App is first invoked:

And this image shows what renders when the checkboxInput() is checked. I would like the below output table from the mainPanel() to render even when the checkboxInput() is not checked, when first invoking the App:

Code:
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

extraFun <- function(input_df, time_win, col_name) {
  df <- setNames(data.frame(rep(NA, time_win)), col_name)
  df[,col_name] <- 
    ifelse(seq_along(df[,1])%in%input_df[,1],input_df[match(seq_along(df[,1]),input_df[,1]),2],0)
  return(df)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    h5(strong("Variable (Y) over window (W):")),
    rHandsontableOutput("parentTbl"), 
    checkboxInput("showCurves", HTML("<b>Add curves</b>"), FALSE),  
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.showCurves == true",
      uiOutput("childTbl")
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(tableOutput("mainTbl"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  parentVars  <- lapply(1:2, function(i) { reactiveValues(data = 2) })
  grpInputs   <- reactiveValues(tables = list())
  plus        <- reactive(extraFun(grpInputs$tbl[["A"]],10,"A"))
  minus       <- reactive(extraFun(grpInputs$tbl[["B"]],10,"B"))
  
  output$parentTbl <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(
      data.frame(Inputs = sapply(parentVars, function(x) x$data)),
      rowHeaders = c("A","B")
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$parentTbl, {
    newValues <- hot_to_r(input$parentTbl)$Inputs
    for (i in 1:2) {parentVars[[i]]$data <- newValues[i]}
  })
 
  # Below builds child X/Y tables #
  lapply(1:2, function(i) {
    varInputId <- c("A","B")[i]
    output[[varInputId]] <- renderRHandsontable({
      df <- data.frame(X = 1, Y = parentVars[[i]]$data)
      rhandsontable(df, contextMenu = TRUE, rowHeaders = FALSE) 
    })
  })
  
  output$childTbl <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:2, function(i) {
      varInputId <- c("A","B")[i]
      list(
        h5(strong(paste("Adjust ", varInputId, " (Y) at time X:"))),
        rHandsontableOutput(varInputId)
      )
    })
  })
  
  observe({
    lapply(1:2, function(i) {
      varInputId <- c("A","B")[i]
      if (!is.null(input[[varInputId]])) {
        grpInputs$tbl[[i]] <- hot_to_r(input[[varInputId]])
        names(grpInputs$tbl)[i] <- varInputId
      }
    })
  })
  
  amCrs <- reactive({
    balances <- cumprod(c(1, 1+plus()[1:10,1]-minus()[1:10,1]))
    b <- head(balances, -1)
    result <- data.frame(
      Begin=b,Add=b*plus()[1:10,1],Subtract=b*minus()[1:10,1],End=balances[-1]
    )
  })
  
  output$mainTbl <- renderTable({
    req(length(grpInputs$tbl) > 0)
    amCrs()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


I think this is an interesting question. The mainTbl is reliant on the inputs in the childTbl, but these inputs don't really exist when the conditionalPanel criteria is not met. I wonder if you can store the results in a reactiveValues() which can exist even if the conditionalPanel criteria is not met. I admit, the app is a little more complex than the time I have, so I can't test this idea.

Dropping the uiOutput could also help, swapping it for inputs that can be updated on the server side.

I recommend rethinking the overall approach here as @Silentdevildoll has suggested, but as a hack you could (1) add shinyjs::useShinyjs() to your ui, (2) set showCurves to be initially checked, and (3) add shinyjs::delay(10, shinyjs::click("showCurves")) to the end of your server.

The S. Laurent solution, accepted, does the trick. I noticed a quirk when running only his suggested change where the child tables would not render even if the checkboxInput() was checked unless and until the parent table was clicked on. I show below a hackish solution to this quirk. Now the child table renders when the checkboxInput() is checked without the user having to first interact with the parent table:
output$childTbl <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:2, function(i) {
      varInputId <- c("A","B")[i]
      list(
        h5(strong(paste("Adjust ", varInputId, " (Y) at time X:"))),

        # VILLAGE ADDED THIS:
        if(input$showCurves==TRUE || input$showCurves==FALSE) {
          rHandsontableOutput(varInputId)
          }
      )
    })
  })


Add outputOptions(output, varInputId, suspendWhenHidden = FALSE) here:
  lapply(1:2, function(i) {
    varInputId <- c("A","B")[i]
    output[[varInputId]] <- renderRHandsontable({
      df <- data.frame(X = 1, Y = parentVars[[i]]$data)
      rhandsontable(df, contextMenu = TRUE, rowHeaders = FALSE) 
    })
    outputOptions(output, varInputId, suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  })

